# ConditionalWeakTable with EventHandler as Key

Tags: c#

I tried to store an EventHandler as key into a ConditionalWeakTable but if I try to access the value it couldn't be found.

```
var eventReceiver = new StateChangedEventReceiver();

var dict = new ConditionalWeakTable<EventHandler<EventArgs>, string>();
dict.Add(eventReceiver.OnStateChanged, "Foobar");

string dummy;
dict.TryGetValue(eventReceiver.OnStateChanged, out dummy); // returns false!!!
```

The Code of the StateChangedEventReceiver looks like this:

```
public class StateChangedEventReceiver
{
    public void OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
    }
}
```

I tested the same behavior using a Dictionary and it works as expected:

```
var eventReceiver = new StateChangedEventReceiver();

var dict = new Dictionary<EventHandler<EventArgs>, string>();
dict.Add(eventReceiver.OnStateChanged, "Foobar");

string dummy;
dict.TryGetValue(eventReceiver.OnStateChanged, out dummy); // returns true -> as expected
```

Why?

There's no constructor of ConditionalWeakTable that takes a comparer. I try to "port" (I don't have the source code) the WeakEventManager-Class from .Net 4.5 to .Net 4.0 because I need it and we could not update to .Net 4.0. All I did works correct but I couldn't remove any event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `eventReceiver.OnStateChanged` and convert that expression to a `EventHandler<EventArgs>` you're creating a fresh delegate instance every time. A method by itself has no single associated delegate. You can have arbitrarily many delegates bound to the same method.

The `ConditionalWeakTable` class seems to use reference equality for its keys. It is a shame that it is not possible to build a custom `ConditionalWeakTable` with different semantics because the underlying `internal struct DependentHandle` facility is not public.

Solution: Always pass the same delegate instance.

Comment: I'm not able to add the same delegate instance to the ConditionalWeakTable because the public interface of the WeakEventManager takes an EventHandler-instance and I'm not able to force the user to pass the same instance every time. Maybe I'm able to memorize all registered event handlers together with the unique delegate (storing in a dictionary will not work because the keys/values could not be garbage collected).

Comment: I testet your idea and you're right. I vorgot that the assignment of a method to a delegate creates a new delegate-instance.
The problem is that I'm still not able to pass the same instance every time.

Comment: I have two ideas: Either remember all event handlers that you have ever seen (maybe using weak references to not affect object lifetimes), or pry open `ConditionalWeakTable` and `DependentHandle` using reflection and build a custom `ConditionalWeakTable`. Expect that code to break on the next major version of the framework... You can start with the source code of `ConditionalWeakTable` and only need to do private calls to `DependentHandle`.

Comment: `WeakEventManager` does not seem to use `ConditionalWeakTable` at all. It is just a weak hashtable. No `DependentHandle` needed at all. Just normal `GCHandle`s.

Comment: Thx for the information. I'll try to use a weak hashtable (I tried to find it using google but I didn't found it.) The only hint for a weak hashtable is [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/03/03/building-a-weakreference-hashtable.aspx). This implementation doesn't clean up automatically. I'll try to find a better solution. Thx for your inspiration.